# Setting buttons disabled text colour programatically

Tags: android, button, dialog, textcolor

I cant seem to get the text colour to change of the button from my dialog fragment. This button is generated programatically so I am unable to simply set the style in the xml.

This is what I tried:

```
dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL).setEnabled(false);
dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.message_count_colour));
```

and this is my message_count_colour xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@android:color/white" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:color="@android:color/white" />
</selector>
```

For some reason the disabled button stays the greyed out colour rather than white and I do not know why. Could someone help please

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [getColorStateList()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getColorStateList%28int%29).

Using  `btn.setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.message_count_colour));` this line of code can work.